# WebSockets in Cloud Run, but with Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-run

A tutorial published by Google describes how to build a Chat services using WebSockets and Redis Pub/Sub: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/websockets

The tutorial uses Node.js with Redis Pub/Sub on the server side.  It also uses the socket.io redis adapter to ensure that emitted events are broadcast across all Cloud Run instances so that all connected WebSockets have a chance at processing the event regardless as to which server instance it is connected to.

The client and server code can then be written as if there is logically one cloud run service with access to all socket.io rooms.  The client can join a room and listen for events, and the server to emit events to any room it wants knowing that it will make it to all subscribers.

How would the same thing be achieved using a Spring Boot based service on cloud run, and Google's Pub/Sub as the Pub/Sub mechanism?  I'm not so concerned about the storing of messages.  Rather, I'm trying to figure out how to get events that are published to a topic to get broadcast to the correct WebSocket that is associated with some kind of room or conversation id.

The Redis Pub/Sub and Adapter solution seems to only be available in Node.js.  And I'm not sure what it's doing under the hood to efficiently broadcast events to all instances of the service in order to ensure that it gets delivered to the right WebSocket.  My best guess is that it would involve a fanout mechanism in pub/sub along with some ConcurrentHashMaps to keep track of all the connected WebSockets.

If there are any open source libraries or tools that can simplify some of this that would be ideal.  I would work with STOMP potentially, however in my situation RabbitMQ is not available.  Only Google Pub/Sub.

Surely there's a way to do the same thing this tutorial does but in Java with the same level of simplicity.

Specifically I want to allow each WebSocket connection to subscribe to a conversation.  Any time a producer publishes a message associated with that conversation, I want the subscribed WebSocketSessions to receive that message.

With STOMP, the front end could subscribe to /topic/conv12345 and producers could publish to it.  In the linked tutorial it used socket.io rooms.  I'm trying to do it with Google Pub/Sub which is not a STOMP relay broker.

Comment: This question is a little too general. You would need to detail certain things you have tried and issues you are having with them so that there is more focus.

Comment: @KamalAboul-Hosn added a couple more paragraphs at the end describing what I'm trying to do and what I've seen and tried already.  does that make it less general?